# a new method to solve some congruence problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, determinant

I'm new to number theory and I've newly learnt congruence and there are a special kind of questions in my book which I usually face problems to solve an example of them is as follows:

> If $18a\equiv12b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 9)$ then which of the following statments is wrong?
> $$(1)\ a\equiv0\ (\mathrm{mod}\  2)$$
> $$(2)\ b\equiv0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$
> $$(3)\ 3a\equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$
> $$(4)\ 3a\equiv2b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

The point is that I can solve them but with a long and hard effort so I was thinking of a shorter way and I remember the short way my teacher told me for division problems which is as follows:

If $d|2n+5, d|9n+2$,then $d|\det\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 5 \\
9 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ but he also mentioned that we have to check the determinant for paradoxes.

Anyway I don't know where this formula has come from and I wonder to know two things.

1. Where does this method come from and can I use it for the problems I mentioned first(since you can write every congruence as a division)?

Actually I have some ideas when they don't change to $\mathrm{mod}$ in question choices but I don't know what to do when there's a change in the base.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Three tips:

- You can divide both sides of a congruence by an integer if you divide the modulus by that same integer; so for instance, $18a\equiv12b \pmod 9$ is exactly the same as $6a\equiv4b \pmod 3$.
- We might as well reduce all integers that appear modulo the modulus; so for instance, since $6\equiv0\pmod3$ and $4\equiv1\pmod3$, we know that $6a\equiv4b \pmod 3$ is exactly the same as $0a\equiv1b \pmod 3$, or $b\equiv0\pmod3$.
- Finally, if two moduli are relatively prime, then whether the congruences hold or not are completely independent of each other. For example, since $\gcd(9,2)=1$, whether $18a\equiv12b \pmod 9$ is completely independent of whether $a\equiv0\pmod 2$ (they might be both true, both false, or one of each either way).

Comment: thanks both for your edit and tips on solving the problem but which is more important to me is the determinant solving method and how it works.